# Need feedback on displaying tabs with icons

Tags: usability, icons, tabs

We're building a GIS application for the Police Department.
I have a widget called "Camera" and in that widget, we've added multiple camera locations as per their geo-ids.

The camera widget will create a new TAB, with the CALL NUMBER (for e.g. MP190020020) as the title, and a subtitle (for e.g. Man w/Gun) and will be the ACTIVE Tab.

Users can navigate between tabs. “Pinning” a tab prevents the tab from being replaced by the system when a new buffer is created – If it is pinned, the next System Tab will display to the left between “Pinned Tabs” and Default Tab” with other four icons

I've been given two options:

- Option 1: Pinned icon and close icon are placed on the tab. There is difficulty in click/Call to action.
- Option 2: the other four icons are shown as a drop-down menu: It does not looks perfect.

What are some good options with better usability for placement of pinned and close icon?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is about the pin and close button, but the images show a difference in the extra menu being visible vs. hidden. You should focus on one specific question. The main point is: how important is each option = how big it should be. You can also make use extra things like double click, right click etc. for pinning to make it easier besides the icon.

Comment: And btw, the strike through pin icon looks like a satellite or something. Maybe the line could be placed better :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the second option because in the first one it is not obvious if those icons are contextual to the selected tab. They seem to have global functionality rather than affecting a particular tab.